# using python to open many idle windows

Tags: python-3.x, python-idle

i have this layout

```
1/mainy.py
2/main.py
3/main.py
........
```

i wish to run each "main" in its own idle window. not a cmd line because if it crashes i tend to lose the output.

so far i have

```
for i in range(150):
    i+=1 # because theres no zero folder
    exec(open(str(i)+"/"+'main.py').read()) # if i run this in idle it tries to run them in the same idle window
```

[image]

i want to have many different idle windows simultaneaously. right now i have to open each manually but i want a script to do it.

i very specfically want each one running in its own idle window so i should have 8 (9 including the one that opens the rest) windows open.

Comment: Do you need to collect the output for each script in your main script?

Comment: no just run each one in its own idle

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to collect output from each idle, you can use `subprocess.Popen`

```
from subprocess import *
import os

#Loop over and change script name
for i in range(150):
    script_name = os.path.join(str(i), "main.py")
    print('script launching:', script_name)
    subprocess.Popen("start python " + script_name, stdin=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, shell=True)
```

Comment: the slash is for folder not file name because each one is in a different folder but i really do want them in their own shell in their own window.

Comment: In that case use os.path.join() to make the paths to scripts, I will update my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can open each Python script in separate window using this:

```
import subprocess
import time
import pyautogui

for i in range(150):
    i+=1 # because theres no zero folder   
    subprocess.call([ 'C:/Users/tgmjack/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/Lib/idlelib/idle.bat', str(i)+"/"+'main.py'])
    time.sleep(2)
    pyautogui.press('f5')
    time.sleep(2)
```

Change the first path to match where idle.bat is located and the second according to your Python script.
You can loop through the scripts but you have to use PyAutoGUI package to press F5 to run each script programmatically.
Refer to https://pypi.org/project/PyAutoGUI/